# Signature in my canvas is not working on mobiles

Tags: javascript, class, html5-canvas, touch-event

My script is working fine on desktop, but not on mobiles.
The script is working like this :

1. The user click on a button
2. The button clicked open a modal
3. the user signs inside a canvas located inside the modal.

On Desktop, it works fine. But not on mobile devices.

Can you help me to correct my code ?

Here is the page : http://p4547.phpnet.org/velos/modal/

I already added the touchstart, touchmove and touchend functions, but it's not working.

Here is my code :

```
"use strict";
class Signature {
    constructor() {
        this.color = "#000000";
        this.sign = false;
        this.begin_sign = false;
        this.width_line = 5;
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.offsetLeft = this.canvas.offsetLeft;
        this.offsetTop = this.canvas.offsetTop;
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.context.lineJoin = 'round'; // jointure arrondie
        this.context.lineCap = 'round'; // extrémité arrondie
        this.whenActionDown();
        this.whenActionUp();
        this.whenActionMove();
        this.createSignature();
        this.clearCanvas();
        this.resetCanvas();
    }
    // Mise à jour de la position de la souris car c'est dans une modal
    updateMousePosition(mX, mY) {
    let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let scaleX = this.canvas.width / rect.width;
    let scaleY = this.canvas.height / rect.height;
    this.cursorX = (mX - rect.left) * scaleX;
    this.cursorY = (mY - rect.top) * scaleY;
}

    actionDown(e) {
        this.sign = true;
        this.updateMousePosition(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    actionUp() {
        this.sign = false;
        this.begin_sign = false;
    }

    actionMove(e) {
        if (this.sign) {
            this.updateMousePosition(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            this.createSignature();
        }
    }


    // La signature commence lorsqu'on clique sur la souris :
    whenActionDown() {
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.actionDown.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", this.actionDown.bind(this));
    }

    // Relâchement du clic. On arrête la signature :
    whenActionUp() {
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.actionUp.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener("touchend", this.actionUp.bind(this));
    }

    // Mouvement de la souris sur le canvas :
    whenActionMove() {
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.actionMove.bind(this));
        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', this.actionMove.bind(this));
    }

    // Fonction qui permet la création de la signature :
    createSignature() {
        // Si c'est le début, la signature démarre :
        if (!this.begin_sign) {
            // Placement du curseur pour la première fois :
            this.context.beginPath();
            this.context.moveTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
            this.begin_sign = true;
        }
        // Sinon on signe :
        else {
            this.context.lineTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
            this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
            this.context.lineWidth = this.width_line;
            this.context.stroke();
        }
    }
    // Nettoyage du Canvas :
    clearCanvas() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.offsetWidth, this.canvas.offsetHeight);
    }
    // Reset :
    resetCanvas() {
        document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.clearCanvas();
        })
    }
}
// Instanciation de la Signature :
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    new Signature();
});
```

Please note : I'm still a beginner, and I already searched solutions on Google, but without any success.

Comment: Do the touch events fire as expected? What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Bergi the touch events (on mobile) does not work. If the user tries to sign on mobile, nothing happens.

Comment: Touch events (on mobile) does not work because you do not detect for touches. Unlike the mouse events, if you are working with touches the user can touch the screen on several points. So instead of working with an event you are working with event.touches[0]. Also when working with touches you will need to call `event.preventDefault()` _"to keep the browser from continuing to process the touch event"_ Please take a look at this demo: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/55b9a9c8a816ec43f2765fb2e1b8354d